# How to get this data using the loop?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

**How do i show all the data by using the loop to display all the data from json to html ?**

ATM , I am able to print one of the data. but if i am using data[i] the code will not display any data.

I think I mess up the the concept of object and array. 
please advice me , how to loop thru object , like array?

thanks

```js
var getWeather =  document.getElementById('weather');

var requestWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();

//+'-31' +'&lon='+'150'

requestWeather.open('GET','https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=-31&lon=150');
requestWeather.onload = function () {
    var weatherData = JSON.parse(requestWeather.responseText);
    console.log(weatherData);
    getHTML(weatherData);
};

requestWeather.send();

function getHTML(data) {
    var weatherString = "";

    for(var i in data.weather ){

        var x=  data.weather[i].main;
    weatherString+= "<p class='weather'>"  + x + "</p>";
    // weatherString+= "<p>"  + data.currently.summary + "</p>";
    // console.log(data[i].city);
    }
    
    
    getWeather.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", weatherString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weather"></div>
```

Comment: the api only returns one element, not an array of elements to iterate over

Comment: yep, if I wanna show every single data, I have to do it manually? like one by one ?

Comment: well... `.main` is there only once, you'd have to get the other keys like you do with `.main`

Comment: Ok ~ I am wondering if there is an alternative way to do that ...

Comment: its also gonna be a problem if I wanna get the main array. there is another array call [main]. in this case, I need to loop that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all data check for object and do recursive loop

```js
var getWeather = document.getElementById('weather');

var requestWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();

//+'-31' +'&lon='+'150'

requestWeather.open('GET', 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=-31&lon=150');
requestWeather.onload = function() {
  var weatherData = JSON.parse(requestWeather.responseText);
  //console.log(weatherData);
  getHTML(weatherData);
};

requestWeather.send();

function getHTML(data) {
  var weatherString = "";
  for(var i in data) {
    var x = data[i];
    if(typeof(x) == "object") {
      getHTML(x);
    }
    else {
      weatherString += "<p class='weather'><b>" + i + "</b>: " + x + "</p>";
      // weatherString+= "<p>"  + data.currently.summary + "</p>";
      // console.log(data[i].city);
    }
  }
  getWeather.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", weatherString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weather"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @ewwink , it's a nice approach. but I am thinking is there any way to access each data like data.weather[i].main; after loop you thru the data?cos eventually, I wanna use the object. eg. icon url

Comment: no need loop if you want to get one value, you just need index and key for example to get icon `data.weather[0].icon`

Comment: your code is correct but `data.weather` only having 1 object so it not efficient using loop, except you want o get all `data.weather[0]` do `for(var i in data.weather[0] ){
        var x=  data.weather[0][i];`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var getWeather = document.getElementById('weather');

var requestWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();

//+'-31' +'&lon='+'150'

requestWeather.open('GET', 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=-31&lon=150');
requestWeather.onload = function() {
  var weatherData = JSON.parse(requestWeather.responseText);
  
  getHTML(weatherData);
};

requestWeather.send();

function getHTML(data) {
  var weatherString = "";

  for (var i in data.weather) {

    var x = data.weather[i].main;
    weatherString += "<p class='weather'>" + x + "</p>";

    $.each(data.main, function(i, f) {
      var main = "<div>" + i + ": " + f + "</div>";
      $(main).appendTo("#main");
    });
  }


  getWeather.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", weatherString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weather"></div>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Uhm, how do I get object data then?

Answer (score 0):

use foreach loop to iterate over all object
[read more from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: for each only take array not objects?

Comment: @Fenici It is also possible to convert **object** into **array** [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)